Download entire github repository as zip through fetch in browser memory to further edit before downloading to user
Context
I have a GitHub repository that includes various subfolders with different modules (versioned through releases). I am trying to create a website (without a backend server) that lets the user pick and choose which modules they want and automatically combine them instead of needing to downloading & combining them manually.
The plan

let the user choose which version and which modules from that version they want
download the zip of the repo at that point in time into memory
modify the zip to remove/modify the modules as needed
download the zip to the users computer

(alternatively I could substitute #2 for downloading the various modules and combining them, but from my research so far that seems a lot more difficult anyways)
The issue
Step 2 is where the issue comes in, everything else I've basically figured out. For the life of me I cannot figure out a way to download an entire repository as a zip to memory for further changes.
I tried fetching the API in various different ways, all of which resulted in a 302 (or occasionally 404) code, combined with a CORS error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at . (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 302

fetch(`https://github.com/user/project/archive/${release.tag_name}.zip`)
fetch(`https://github.com/user/project/archive/refs/tags/${release.tag_name}.zip`)
fetch(`https://github.com/user/project/zipball/${release.tag_name}`)

// slightly different error (notice the different url):
// Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://codeload.github.com/user/project/legacy.zip/refs/tags/v2.0.0. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://render.githubusercontent.com’) 
fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/user/project/zipball/${release.tag_name}`)

Possible solutions I've also looked at but failed to implement
I've found this github api page on CORS and JSONP but I do not understand how it could help me in my situation. (Doesn't help that their minimal example fails due to a MIME type mismatch)
I've also found answers such as this one that references various third party solutions specifically to download specific folders on GitHub, but that's generally achieved through fetching all files individually, using up the non-authenticated github api rate limit real quick. And we can't ask users to add their own API token first.
Conclusion
The only other solution I can think of is to save the zip files manually somewhere (or automatically through github actions or something) and serve them in a cors-problem-free environment such as on github pages, but that would be duplicating sources and that's very much suboptimal.
I'm thankful for any and all pointers, whether it's towards solving one of my issues with my own solution attempts or coming up with a new approach that would solve the original issue.
